# Need to get the count of all the rows in all the groups in ag-grid with aggregation on it

Tags: ag-grid

I'm using grouping in ag-grid and I need to get the count of all the records present in all the groups. The individual count of the group is already being displayed in the grid right in front of the group name in (). 
[I need the sum of highlighted counts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uokH2.png)

The count is being displayed with "eChildCount" ref, I can get it using jQuery selectors, but I feel, it'll be a little clumsy as I need to handle grouping and normal scenarios as well, I'm looking for any solution that could give me the results by using ag-grid options directly or indirectly. There are some references given for "forEachNodeAfterFilter(callback)" but, I'm not sure how would it work, small code snippet would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gridOptions.api.getModel().rootNode.allChildrenCount` is what you are looking for. `getModel()` has lots of information available to you about the rows that are in the grid